# Multiple regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Is there a better to handle running multiple regular expressions in PHP (or in general)?

I have the code below to replace non alphanumeric characters with dashes, once the replacement has happened I want to remove the instances of multiple dashes.

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/i', '-', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/\-{2,}/i', '-', $slug);
```

Is there a neater way to do this? ie, setup the regex pattern to replace one pattern and then the other?

(I'm like a kid with a fork in a socket when it comes to regex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eliminate the second `preg_replace` by saying what you really mean in the first one:

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', $slug);
```

What you really mean is "replace all sequences of one or more non-alphanumeric characters with a single hyphen" and that's what `/[^a-z0-9]+/i` does. Also, you don't need to include the upper and lower case letters when you specify a case insensitive regex so I took that out.

Answer (score 2):

No. What you have is the appropriate way to deal with this problem.

Consider it from this angle: regular expressions are meant to find a pattern (a *single* pattern) and deal with it somehow. As such, by trying to deal with more than one pattern at a time, you're only giving yourself headaches. It's best as is, for everyone involved.

Answer (score 0):

If `$slug` already doesn't have multiple hyphens then you can avoid 2nd preg_replace call by using first preg_replace call like this:

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+-?/i', '-', $slug);
```

Above code will find non-alphanumeric character **optionally followed** by hyphen and replace that matched text by a single hyphen `-`. hence no need to make 2nd preg_replace call.

Comment: See the accepted answer for a variation on what you're suggesting, which in my opinion is a bit more flexible. Thanks for the reply though.